# Java 8 vs Java 7 Collection Interface: self-referential instance

Tags: java-8, java-7

I was reading Java 8 collection interface documentation. I noticed [Java 8 Collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) added this paragraph in the description which is not included in [Java 7 Collection Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) .

> Some collection operations which perform recursive traversal of the
>   collection may fail with an exception for self-referential instances
>   where the collection directly or indirectly contains itself. This
>   includes the clone(), equals(), hashCode() and toString() methods.
>   Implementations may optionally handle the self-referential scenario,
>   however most current implementations do not do so.

I am a little confused as of why this paragraph is included. Is it because Java 7 cannot have self-referential instances where collection directly or indirectly contains itself? Then Java 8 introduced new interface or some new feature that allows that?

I am looking for detail explanations and it will be great if you includes an example to illustrate your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it because Java7 cannot have self-referential instances where
>   collection directly or indirectly contains itself?
>    Then Java8 introduced new interface or some new feature that allows
>   that?

I don't think so.
Before Java 8, instances may of course have self reference. 
And using them in a `Collection` may create of course infinite loops and failure at runtime with a `StackOverflowError` thrown.

Here two classes where instance fields have circular dependencies between them and which the `toString()` method of each class  relies on their own fields.

Parent that refers to Child :

```
public class Parent {
    private List<Child> childs;

    public Parent(List<Child> childs) {
       this.childs = childs;
    }   

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Parent [childs=" + childs + "]";
    }

}
```

Child that refers to Parent :

```
public class Child {
    private Parent parent;

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Child [parent=" + parent + "]";
    }

}
```

Suppose now you create a Child and a associated Parent :

```
List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
Child child = new Child();
childs.add(child);

Parent parent = new Parent(childs);
child.setParent(parent);
```

Now you can invoke :

```
parent.toString();
child.toString();
```

or on a `Collection` instance such as :

```
childs.toString();
```

You will get exactly the same result : `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

as the child invokes the parent that invokes the child that invokes the parent and so on...

The doc was very probably updated with Java 8 to enforce the risk of implementing these methods in a brittle way as the `Collection` implementations generally don't address it and it makes sense as hiding the malfunctioning of a bugged client code has to be avoided otherwise the problem will never be solved.

> "Implementations may optionally handle the self-referential scenario,
>   however most current implementations do not do so."

Comment: +1 thank you for such detailed explanation. I am having trouble to see `parent.toString();` `child.toString();` invokes each other. it would make sens to me if the return statment is like this  `return "Parent [childs=" + childs.toString() + "]";`but I only see `return "Parent [childs=" + childs + "]";` and `return "Child [parent=" + parent + "]";`

Comment: You are welcome :) When you concatenate a `String` with a object that is not declared as a `String` (literal String included)  as here `"Parent [childs=" + childs + "]"` the compiler applies the `String.valueOf(Object)` method for each one of these objects. So it is finally interpreted as `"Parent [childs=" + String.valueOf(childs)) + "]"` that is `"Parent [childs=" + childs.toString() + "]"` with in bonus the not null check for `childs` to prevent a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: wow I didn't know `String.valueOf(Object)` return `obj.toString()`, thanks! :) . One more thing I want to ask for clarification before I accept this as the answer. Why did you mentiond `Collection` instance such as", The `toString()` method here is from the `ArrayList` class right? which is also the same method  `Parent` and Child` class `@Override`? I know the `toString` in `ArrayList` is inherited from `AbstractCollection` class. And `AbstractCollection` implements `Collection`....is that why? I am a little confused here

Comment: No problem :) I would just stress that the problem is not caused by the  `toString()` implementation of `ArrayList` . Invoking `toString()` on the object contained in the `List` or directly on the `List` triggers the same error. As said at the end of my answer, Collection implementations don't try generally to address/recover the "bugged" behavior of the instances that they store and manipulate.

Comment: ahh I got the point. I am refreshing memory on class inheritance and implementation. You are a very experienced Java developer so I wanted to use this chance to fleshing up my memory. Does `Collection` implement `toString()`?  I don't see it in the Collection Interface.

Comment: No problem :) The `toString()` method is declared in the `Object` class. Every class extend `Object` implicitly or indirectly if it inherits from another class. So by extension all classes "implement" `toString()` or to be more exact : inherit the `toString()` method.

Comment: Thank you so much davidxxx you rock!

Answer (score 6):

The `toString()` format for `List` is specified; it must recursively `toString()` the contents and render them in a comma-separated list delimited by `[ ... ]`.  If you create a `List` as follows:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(list);
System.out.println(list);
```

a naive implementation of `toString()` would throw `StackOverflowError` (try it.)  The `Collection` implementations try to defend against this problem for some core methods, in some cases; that's what this paragraph is saying.

Comment: It says, [(this Collection)]